# Display "Page 3 of 5" for a paginated post

Tags: pagination

I have a custom post type that I want to display the page you are on and how many pages total in this manner "Page 3 of 5" (meaning you are on page 3 of a 5 page post).  These don't have to be links, just plain text numbers.

I'd still like to keep the standard function of the wp_page_links parameter "next_or_number" set to "next", but add this other page indicator.

I've tried experimenting with making my own funciton with some of the variables in the wp_page_links function on line 567 of the [post-template.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.3/wp-includes/post-template.php) file but I didn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current / total page count is set up by `setup_postdata()` which runs at the beginning of the loop. So, if you're in the loop, all you have to do is this:

```
global $page, $numpages;
echo "Page $page of $numpages";
```

If you need to do that outside of the loop, do this first:

```
global $page, $post, $numpages;
// This next line is optional: sets a new global $post variable
$post = get_post(123);
setup_postdata($post);
echo "Page $page of $numpages";
```